# getNestedList() method seems return wrong order in etrepat/baum laravel Package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, nested-sets, nested-set-model

According to [**etrepat/baum**](https://github.com/etrepat/baum#) Docs, **getNestedList()** must return a key-value pair array indicating a node's depth with a separator.

This is my Table data and Structure :
[image]

By this Code :

```
$categories = Category::getNestedList('name',NULL,'-');
return $categories;
```

Result is :

[image]

While it should look like this

[image]

means that ever child Category must came immediately after it's Parent and order by **lft** column field But **getNestedList()** Does not this wotk and return Categories In the same way that are inserted to Table.

How can I do my purpose ?